# /me/photos is incomplete

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos, restfb

I'm using the GraphAPI Explorer (and also the java restFB library) and when I query /me/photos, I only get five of the photos I am tagged in when there are more.  If I try access a photo not showing up directly the explorer just gives me 'false'.

As far as permissions I pretty much checked anything photo/video related just in case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Graph API is using paging, so it only return 25 items at a time.

It also returns a link to the previous and next set of items:

```
"paging": {
    "previous": "facebook previous link", 
    "next": "facebook next link"
}
```